# Write a Higher Order Function for haskell code

Tags: haskell

Here are some haskell function definitions.

```
f1 (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x+y) : f1 xs ys
f1 _ _ = []
f2 (xs:xss) (ys:yss) = (xs++ys) : f2 xss yss
f2 _ _ = []
f3 (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x*y) : f3 xs ys
f3 _ _ = []
f4 (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x+42) : f4 xs ys
f4 _ _ = []
f5 (x:xs) (y:ys) = (y-x*x) : f5 xs ys
f5 _ _ = []
```

So, I need to make a higher-order function hof that captures this common behaviour and rewrite each of f1, f2, f3, f4, and f5 above, to be a call to hof with
appropriate arguments. Finally, unrelated to the previous parts, is hof provided by the Haskell Prelude (under another name)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
hof f list1 list2 = zipWith f list1 list2

f1 list1 list2 = hof (+) list1 list2

f2 list1 list2 = hof (++) list1 list2

f3 list1 list2 = hof (*) list1 list2

f4 list1 list2 = hof func list1 list2
                where func x _ = x+42

f5 list1 list2 = hof func list1 list2
                where func x y = y - (x*x)
```